# Can a Vulkan Pipeline only accept one kind of input primitive?

Tags: vulkan

In the call to `vkCreateGraphicsPipelines` only one `VkPipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo` can be specified for the whole Pipeline. I was originally thinking I'd have multiple subpasses, the first taking a vertex buffer of `VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_POINT_LIST`, the second a `VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_LINE_LIST`, and the third a `VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLE_LIST`. Is this not possible?

Comment: Why would you use separate subpasses for different topologies? Subpasses are about what you render to; how does that relate to mesh topology?

Answer (score 1):

no you have to create a separate pipeline objects for each primitive type.

However you can specify that the variant pipelines are derived from the main pipeline to speedup creation time.